# Ubuntu 15.10 Release fglrx issue

Tags: drivers, ati, fglrx, 15.10

Just upgraded from 15.04 to 15.10 via `apt-get dist-upgrade`. Nothing was customized, everything running from official repos.

Before upgrade I already purged all `fglrx` proprietary driver from the system and running on standard `radeon` driver.

The upgrade went successful and after booting into new 15.10 im installing fglrx again via `Software & Updates` for proprietary driver, no errors installation was success.

However during booting up to make the driver kicks in, the booting stucked at below error:

`fb: switching to fglrxdrmfb from EFI VGA`

My display:

```
root@mylenovo:/etc/apt/sources.list.d# lshw -c display
  *-display               
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Mullins [Radeon R4/R5 Graphics]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 1
       bus info: pci@0000:00:01.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=radeon latency=0
       resources: irq:37 memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:f0000000-f07fffff ioport:3000(size=256) memory:f0c00000-f0c3ffff memory:f0800000-f081ffff
```

Any thing that I missed causing `fglrx` not to work?

Comment: I provided a workaround for this issue on [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/689714/442302).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I guess you have read the Wily release notes saying

```
AMD's fglrx driver does not work with the current kernel (1493888).
It is warmly recommended to uninstall the fglrx driver before upgrading to
Ubuntu 15.10.
The open source "radeon" driver can be used as a temporary replacement
until a fix is available.
```

Why else would you have removed `fglrx` before upgrade in the first place?

Either downgrade to Kernel 4.1 or use `radeon` until a fix of `fglrx` becomes available.

Bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/fglrx-installer/+bug/1493888

Comment: Ahh i forget the very important thing with new release which is to read the release note first!! Thanks!

Comment: That explains everything… They should pop up a big fat messagebox when core stuff like that is broken.  (Currently, I’m almost sorry for having updated things.) Fact is the fglrx and fglrx causes segfaults within lightdm. I wonder how that boils down to the kernel. Anyway +1

Answer (score 0):

The `fglrx` bug is now solved.

Before, I had to boot on my backup install to disable `fglrx` and use the open driver instead, which is slow. Maybe Grub advanced booting on the same install but using the previous kernel works for those who are stuck.

Since, I updated Ubuntu through Update Manager, and also updated `fglrx-core` package through Synaptics Packager Manager (not sure this is needed). Then, I switched the graphic driver back to `fglrx-update` and rebooted.