# AMD Fglrx Driver causes Ubuntu 15.10 to Crash

Tags: drivers, upgrade, ati, fglrx

I upgraded my Ubuntu 15.04 to Ubuntu 15.10, and it crashed. When I use the old kernel, it boots success with period time of black screen, when I uninstall the AMD Fglrx driver, Ubuntu 15.10 boot success. Then, I reinstall AMD Fglrx by the additional drivers, it crashed. Now, I reinstall new Ubuntu 15.10 by CD with Internet, it crashed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ubuntu 15.10 stuck on booting after installing proprietary amd graphics drivers?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/688644/ubuntu-15-10-stuck-on-booting-after-installing-proprietary-amd-graphics-drivers)

Answer (score 2):

In the Ubuntu 15.10 Release Notes [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WilyWerewolf/ReleaseNotes), it states:

> AMD's fglrx driver does not work with the current kernel (1493888). It is warmly recommended to uninstall the fglrx driver before upgrading to Ubuntu 15.10. The open source "radeon" driver can be used as a temporary replacement until a fix is available.

Comment: Thanks, but it will crash with the Internet connection to install.

Comment: It might be automatically trying to install the fglrx drivers. Installing without an internet connection might solve this.